# How to get different styles - in particular background colors - in list view rows on Android?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have been trying for too many hours now myself and can't get the background color to change for rows in list view.

This is my code:

```
public class InteractiveArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Object> {

    private final List<Object> list;
    private final Activity context;

    public InteractiveArrayAdapter(Activity context, List<Object> list) {
       super(context, R.layout.rowbuttonlayout, list);
       this.context = context;
       this.list = list;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
       protected TextView text;
       protected CheckBox checkbox;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.rowbuttonlayout, null);
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
        viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
        viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
    } else {
        view = convertView;
        ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
    }
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    Object obj = list.get(position);

    //if we have a String object it's a different style 
    if (obj.getClass() == String.class) {
        holder.text.setText((String) obj);
        holder.checkbox.setVisibility(View.GONE);

      /* tried this - does not work 
        view.setBackgroundColor(0xAAAA);
        */

        holder.text.setTextColor(Color.BLUE); // this is OK
        holder.text.setTextSize((float) 18.0);  // this is OK
    } else { // it's a different row style
        holder.text.setText(x.name);
        holder.checkbox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // this is OK
        holder.text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);       // this is OK
        holder.text.setTextSize((float) 15.0);       // this is OK

    }

    return view;
    }
}
```

and this is the rowbuttonlayout.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="@+id/label"
            android:textSize="12dp" >
        </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Whatever I tried to change the row color - it stays black. The only thing that worked was to introduce an ImageView. But I think this is too much just to change the color of a row.

Also I did not get the row to be filled out fully with the image view.

**So all I am looking for is a solution to set the row color like the other style attributes - that work OK by the way.**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the color of the row being click try this in your ListView Activity or with your ListView.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);        

}
```

Or

```
ListView.onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);        

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes, thanks. This is what I always do too. But why doesn't it work when I overwrite getView ?

Comment: Becuase you are creating a custom view.

Comment: so, what do I have to do, to change the backgorund color in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I may not understand, but does this not work:

```
view.setBackgroundColor(0x222222);
```

Comment: no - it does not change anything. Guess it's because I use my own getView ?? But don't really know.